# Looping through objects and adding them to Sequelize db

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I have an array of objects that I like to put into SQL via Sequelize and I'm running into issues.

```
[ 
  { owner: false,
    id: '2342365',
    name: 'awrAPI' },
  { owner: false,
    id: '5675689699',
    name: 'TgatAPI' },
  { owner: true,
    id: '57456767',
    name: 'ytasyAPI' }
[
```

Currently the way i have it set up is through a simple for in.

```
    for( var key in guilds ) {
        Guild
        .findOrCreate({where: {primid: guilds[key].id}, defaults: {
            primid: guilds[key].id,
            name: guilds[key].name,
            owner: guilds[key].icon
        }})
        .spread(function(guild, created) {
            console.log(guild.get({
            plain: true
            }))
            console.log(created)
        })                      
    }
```

I assume this is wrong and was wondering if there is a better way to loop through my object and chain the findorcreates.  Currently it goes through the first object, but then does not add any more.  I've been looking into using Bluebird, but I'm not too familiar with using promises.  Thoughts?

Comment: What are your "issues"?

Comment: @DanielB "Currently it goes through the first object, but then does not add any more".  I also assume that this shouldn't be the way to handle it and more than likely requires some use of promises.  I'm just not sure

Comment: I suppose, your code throws 'guild is not defined' error, because your spread function recieve first parameter named as `user` but then call function of `guild` instance that isn't defined, they should have same name. Try to change first parameter of spread function to 'guild'

Comment: @TilovYrys Actually that's just a typo.  It is named guild in the actual code Im running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myData = [ 
  { 
    owner: false,
    id: '2342365',
    name: 'awrAPI' 
  },
  { 
    owner: false,
    id: '5675689699',
    name: 'TgatAPI'
  },
  { 
    owner: true,
    id: '57456767',
    name: 'ytasyAPI'
  }
];

Promise.all(myData.map(function(value) {
  // Do your thing
  return Guild.findOrCreate...
})).then(function() {
  // All is resolved do your next thing
})
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I'm not as familiar as map as I'd like to be.  I always assumed that .map only worked on Arrays and not objects.

Comment: True. On the question you hava an array, it was a typo on my answer. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to utilize squelize's bulkCreate model method for multiple records insertion. 
[link to sequelize's bulkCreate docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate)

quick snippet here:

```
 const dataForInsertion = [ 
    {
      username:"daniel",
      currentORM:"Sequelize"
    },
    {
      username:"lekan",
      currentORM:"Mongoose"
    },
 ]

 Guild.bulkCreate(dataForInsertion)
     .then(()=>{})
     .catch(()=>{})
```